# SSID remove duplicates issue

Tags: c++, qt, windows, wifi

I want to remove `wlan SSID` duplicates from `QTreeWidget` or add some checking for the duplicates before displaying in the `QTreeWidget`.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I have tried removing duplicates by `QSet`, but it removes also `SSID` which should be in the list, so it's not working in my case.

**Sample code:**

```
  QStringList apList;

  for (int i = 0; i < (int)pBssList->dwNumberOfItems; i++) {
       pBssEntry = (WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK *)&pBssList->Network[i];
       apList << QString::fromUtf8(reinterpret_cast<char *>(pBssEntry->dot11Ssid.ucSSID), pBssEntry->dot11Ssid.uSSIDLength);
  }

  QSet<QString> apSet = QSet<QString>::fromList(apList);

for (int j = 0; j < apSet.count(); j++) {
    pBssEntry = (WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK *)&pBssList->Network[j];
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8(reinterpret_cast<char *>(pBssEntry->dot11Ssid.ucSSID), pBssEntry->dot11Ssid.uSSIDLength);
}
```

The actual code is very big and complex, containing structures, vectors and vector iteration inserts `QTreeWidgetItems` to the `QTreeWidget`.

I have checked it and it removes last two `SSID`'s as a duplicates.

I want the same behavior as is in `Windows`. Any ideas? Thanks.

**Update:**

```
 QMap<QString, int> apMap;

 for (int i = 0; i < (int)pBssList->dwNumberOfItems; i++) {
      pBssEntry = (WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK *)&pBssList->Network[i];
      apMap.insert(QString::fromUtf8(reinterpret_cast<char *>(pBssEntry->dot11Ssid.ucSSID), pBssEntry->dot11Ssid.uSSIDLength), i);
    }

    qDebug() << apMap.count();
    qDebug() << apMap.uniqueKeys();
    QMap<QString, int>::iterator it;

    for (it = apMap.begin(); it != apMap.end(); it++) {
        qDebug() << it.key();
    }
```

Now it's working, but I need to fix other functionality as well.

**Update: 2**
Finally, I have fixed the bug and add all data to the `QTreeWidget` but sometimes profile column is different with SSID column. The thing is that profile is not added and it displays SSID's instead as is in `Windows OS` in the profile column otherwise it will be empty.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**So the code:**

```
           for (int j = 0; j < apHash.uniqueKeys().count(); j++) {
                pBssEntry = (WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK *)&pBssList->Network[j];
                if (wcslen(pBssEntry->strProfileName) != NULL) {
                    wirelessAPData.profile = QString::fromWCharArray(pBssEntry->strProfileName);
                    wirelessAPData.name = apHash.uniqueKeys().value(j);
                } else {
                    if (!apHash.uniqueKeys().value(j).isEmpty()) {
                        wirelessAPData.profile = apHash.uniqueKeys().value(j);
                        wirelessAPData.name = apHash.uniqueKeys().value(j);
                    } else {
                        wirelessAPData.profile = QObject::tr("Hidden network");
                        wirelessAPData.name = QObject::tr("Hidden network");
                    }
                }
           }
```

Also I have changed the `QMap` to `QHash` to make it faster and `wirelessAPData` is just a `struct`. Thanks.

**Update: 3**
I think there should be better solution, because these `SSID`'s are not duplicates, they have different `Flags`, for example some of them have (`has profile`, `no profile`, `connected`) flags. Also I have created some constants with values:

`3 - connected`,
`2 - has profile`,
`0 - no profile`

And when I check networks with these constants values I get for example only with `no profile` or `has profile` or `connected`. But I need some check to display with `has profile` and only new with `no profile`. Any ideas? Thanks.

**Update: 4:**
I have redesigned the application to support such `APs` (with profiles). The problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `QTreeWidget` doesn't check whether a duplicate is inserted you need to use an additional container which supports exclusion of duplicates such as `QMap` or `QHash`.

Before inserting the items in your tree widget check if the SSID isn't already present (as a key) in your map/hash table. If the check tells that there is such SSID, just don't insert it.

Comment: Ok. I will try it and reply. Thanks.

Comment: I have checked your suggestion, but when inserting to `QMap` the keys are different in my case. So I can't compare it. Code example in my main post.

Comment: "the keys are different in my case" ? But isn't your question about removing duplicates? So an SSID should come twice or even more. Also with `QMap`  you need to be careful with the insertion. As the documentation states if a key already exists inserting a new item with the same key will just replace the item that is stored in the map. So using `QMap::contains` is definitely something that needs to be used before calling insert.

Comment: I have fixed the issue with `QMap`, the problem was with supplying wrong keys. Also there is a `uniqueKeys()` function which returns only unique keys in `QList`. But I lost other information such as Profile, Security and so on. So I need to fix it.

Comment: Profile, security etc. should be put as the value that a key refers to. You can use something as simple as a `struct`. So whenever you access the value for the key `<ssid>` you will actually be getting the properties of the given connection.

Comment: Yes, I use a `struct` with `QVector`, but when all data is inserted, it displays the duplicates or wrong values in some columns. I think there is a bug, so I will recheck my code.

Comment: Hi! I have fixed the bug and insert all data but sometimes profile column is different with SSID column. The thing is that profile is not added and it displays `SSID`'s instead as is in `Windows OS` in the profile column otherwise it will be empty. I will provide the screenshot in my main post to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Then you need to think of another key. Perhaps a combination of both?

Comment: What do you mean by combination of both keys?

Comment: Not of both key but rather of profile AND ssid. You just need to figure what information can be used as a unique identifier for your entry.

Comment: Ok. Unique identifier should be `SSID` column. So I need to use `QHash` for the `Profile` column also? Thanks.

Comment: So I think that I should create another `QHash` object (for Profile) otherwise I will lost unique values for `SSID` column?

Comment: You started with removing SSID duplicates, then you moved to Profile. I'm loosing track here. Is it the SSID or the Profile that defines each data entry and helps you determine whether there is a duplicate or not? I'm not saying that having a separate map/hash table for the profile is not possible but this sounds like overcomplicating something that you just haven't described properly.

Comment: Yes, `SSID`. But the problem is, that not all `SSID` have a `Profile`, so some profile entries are empty, that's why (such as in `OS`) I add also `SSID`'s to the first column (Profile). For example, If profile is present (added) it should display the profile otherwise it displays `SSID`'s in the profile column that's except the `SSID` column which only accepts `SSID`'s.

Comment: I think there should be better solution, because these `SSID`'s are not duplicates, they have different `Flags`, for example some of them have (`has profile`, `no profile`, `connected`) flags. Also I have created some constants with values:

`3 - connected`,
`2 - has profile`,
`0 - no profile`

And when I check networks with these constants values I get for example only with `no profile` or `has profile` or `connected`. But I need some check to display with `has profile` and only new with `no profile`. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it deletes duplicates, though I have redesigned the application.

Comment: Well, you changed the question multiple times. Next time provide as much as possible in one go. ;)